# retrieve array value from jquery in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using a jquery change event using a slider to present to a user the amount of inputs that they select from the slider. I am struggling to find a way to process these results in php and insert into mysql. I would be grateful if someone could start me off with this. Thank you

```
for(var i = 0;i < $(this).val();i++) {
$("#boxamount").append('<div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="boxamount" class="ui-input-text">Enter box ' + (i + 1) + ' number:</label><input type="text" name="boxamount['+i+']" id="boxamount['+i+']" class="boxamount ui-input-text ui-body-null ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-body-c" /></div>')
}
```

Comment: The question is to broad, you have to be more specific. What results do you want to process? Do you want to get all values of the input fields and send them to the server? If so, you can do this with Ajax, and jQuery makes it very easy. Have a look at its documentation.

Comment: @felix I have all the code working apart from being able to retrieve more than 1 value in php using along the lines of:  foreach ($_POST['boxamount'] as $key=>$value)
          {  //do stuff  }}
                $temp = explode(",", $value);
                foreach($temp as $k => $v )
                {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could loop over the text boxes, store the values in an object and submit them via an ajax request. Here's some rough code below.

```
var data = {}; 
$('input[name^="boxamount"]').each(function(){
    data[ $(this).attr('id') ] = $(this).val();  
});
```

Then perform an ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "yourServerScript.php",
   data: data, 
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Comment: instellar the data format I posted, what would be the delimiter? it's not " " or , do you know. thanks